# Simple authentication using angularJS and php

Tags: php, angularjs, mysqli, ionic-framework

It's been more than a week since I read tutorials and questions about authentication, but in vain. I have asked this question several times and every time I go ahead and change the code, but I can not find a solution.

I want to have a simple authentication in my application, Keeping the same structure of the code with which I worked. this is my html file:

login.html

```
<ion-content class="padding" ng-controller="loginCtrl">
<div class="list list-inset" >
<label class="item item-input">
      <input type="text" placeholder="nom" required="" ng-model="NomClient"> 
</label> 
<label class="item item-input">
      <input type="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="mdp"> 
</label> 
    <button class="button button-block button-positive" ng-click="submit()">Login</button>       
 </ion-content>
```

app.js

```
app.controller('loginCtrl', function($scope, $location,$state,$http,$window){

    $scope.submit = function()
    {
        data = {
            'NomClient' : $scope.NomClient,
            'mdp' : $scope.mdp
        };

        $http.post('http://localhost/deb/login.php', data)
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config)
        {
            $window.location.href = '#/admin';
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config)
        {
            console.log('error');
        });
    }

});
```

login.php

```
<?php  

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");  



$NomClient=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->NomClient);
$mdp=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->mdp);


$query = 'SELECT * FROM `client` WHERE NomClient = "'.$NomClient.'" AND   mdp= "'.$mdp.'"';


if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0 )
        { 
            $_SESSION["logged_in"] = true; 
            $_SESSION["naam"] = $NomClient; 
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'The username or password are incorrect!';
        }
 ?>
```

this code doesn't work, because it doesn't check password and username, and it always redirect me to admin view.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there any error in console?

Comment: No error in console, but when I execute login.php file independently, I get Undefined index for NomClient and mdp

Comment: You can tell from the colour formatting of the last segment of code that you have a problem with quotes in your SQL.

Comment: yeah I edit the code, Copy problem

Comment: print value of success -> data in console.log().

Comment: @ Jigarb yeah, thanks for this trick. When I put a wrong password, in console I get this message: The username or password are incorrect, but when I put a right password I don't get any message. now I think the problem is how to redirect to admin view when the password is right!

Comment: @SalamSalam I have update my answer

Answer (score 0):

I have check your code and found one mistake.
Login.php

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($q) > 0 ) //here $q is undefined
```

Second thing is you have to first execute the query as follows:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM `client` WHERE NomClient = "'.$NomClient.'" AND   mdp= "'.$mdp.'"';

$q = mysqli_query($connect , $query);

if(mysqli_num_rows($q) > 0 ){}
```

The final change is

```
$http.post('http://localhost/deb/login.php', data)
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config)
        {
            if(data == "The username or password are incorrect!")
               console.log('error');
            else 
               $window.location.href = '#/admin';
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config)
        {
            console.log('error');
        });
```

Comment: Yes you're right, its '$query' instead of '$q'. I correct it , but I still have the same problem

Comment: I correct it, unfortunatly still have the same problem

Comment: When the password and username are correct, it doesn't redirect me to admin view!

Comment: I m sorry, but now it redirect me to admin view however the password is wrong

Comment: comment what you see in console

Comment: I don't get any error and any message, it just redirect me to admin view

Comment: in your code comment if condition and write console.log(data);

Comment: Yes I did it and I don't get any message

Comment: after submit button click go to `Network tab` click on `localhost/deb/login.php` and select `Preview` tab then show me what you see there

Comment: I get this 2 msg : Trying to get property of non-object of NomClient and mdp and username or password are incorrect

Comment: @SalamSalam, have you check the answer I have edited?

Comment: Yes, i just see it now, and Iedit all changes , but I still have the same problem. Thank you for your help, I m still facing the same problem